# issue in pattern matching in python using glob

Tags: python, pattern-matching, glob

I have directory having file names "VISCUS","MISMANAGE" etc
i want to find files matching given pattern.

pattern = "SALES" # this changes dynamically as command-line args
I am doing like below

```
import glob
files_present = glob.glob(r"*pattern*")
#glob.glob(r"*SALES*")works okay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'*pattern*'` will not change to `'*SALES*'`. Try this:

```
pattern = "SALES"

import glob
files_present = glob.glob(r"*{}*".format(pattern))
```

Comment: how to match files having _ SALES _.
i tried glob.glob(r"*[ _ ]{}[ _ ]*".format(pattern))
but it didn't worked.

Comment: @AshishBainade `glob.glob(r"*_ {} _*".format(pattern))` ?

Comment: i have below files in directory
'VISIONTOUBSR.BLACCTCUSTMTN.NONUBSRONLY.CSV', (having period in between)
'VISIONTOUBSR_BLACCTCUSTMTN_NONUBSRONLY.CSV'(having underscore in between)


i want only file having underscore in between.  glob.glob(r"*_ {} _*".format(pattern)) this gives empty list as return value

Comment: @AshishBainade In your comment, you had space after `_ `. But in file names you don't. So `glob.glob(r"*_{}_*".format(pattern))`.

Comment: still it giving empty list in returns..i even tried setting pattern = "_BLACCTCUSTMTN_" & then using glob.glob(r"*{}*".format(pattern)) but didnt helped

Comment: @AshishBainade Pls show the list of files in your directory and show which do you want to get. If you only have these: `'VISIONTOUBSR.BLACCTCUSTMTN.NONUBSRONLY.CSV', 'VISIONTOUBSR_BLACCTCUSTMTN_NONUBSRONLY.CSV'`, you obviously will not find anythong with `r'*_SALES_*'` pattern

Comment: SALES was typo....updated comment
still it giving empty list in returns..i even tried setting pattern = "BLACCTCUSTMTN" & then using glob.glob(r"{}".format(pattern)) but didnt helped

Comment: @AshishBainade `glob.glob(r"*_{}_*".format(pattern))` works for me (finds only `VISIONTOUBSR_BLACCTCUSTMTN_NONUBSRONLY.CSV`). `glob.glob(r"{}".format(pattern))` will not work because it looks for exactly `BLACCTCUSTMTN` file. `glob.glob(r"*{}*".format(pattern))` finds both files. Check if you are in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
for pattern in ("VISCUS", "MISMANAGE"):
    files_present = glob.glob(r"*{}*".format(pattern))
    # do stuff with present files
```

you create the `glob` string from the loop variable.